# Getting 'Unknown provider: $stateProvider' error with ng-pattern-restrict

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to inject ng-pattern-restrict into my AngularJS project. Following the readme of [Pattern Restrict](https://github.com/AlphaGit/ng-pattern-restrict):

> Finally, add a module reference (typically in app.js) to
>   ngPatternRestrict. e.g.:

In my case, I'm doing it in the controller:

CONTROLLER:

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('webclientesApp', ['ngPatternRestrict'])
        .controller('RegisterController', RegisterController);


    RegisterController.$inject = ['$translate', '$timeout', 'Auth', 'LoginService', 'ValidateService', '$state', '$locale'];

    function RegisterController ($translate, $timeout, Auth, LoginService, ValidateService, $state, $locale) {

...
```

INDEX:

```
<script src="bower_components/ng-pattern-restrict/src/ng-pattern-restrict.js"></script>
```

I did `bower update`, `gulp inject`, but had no luck with that, getting 'Unknown provider' error everytime. Lots of questions involving this problem, but couldn't find the exact root of the issue.

Comment: [Working plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/QHgV7m9jlSLPImxcFif2?p=preview)

Comment: Yes, also tried `var app = angular.module('webclientesApp', ['ngPatternRestrict']); app.controller('RegisterController', RegisterController);`, and is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Silly question, simple answer.

I was injecting the module in the wrong place. In a JHipster project dependencies are informed in the **app.module.js** file:

```
(function() {
'use strict';

angular
    .module('webclientesApp', [
        'ngStorage',
        'tmh.dynamicLocale',
        'pascalprecht.translate',
        'ngResource',
        'ngCookies',
        'ngAria',
        'ngCacheBuster',
        'ngPatternRestrict',
        'ngFileUpload',
        'ui.bootstrap',
        'ui.bootstrap.datetimepicker',
        'ui.router',
        'infinite-scroll',
        // jhipster-needle-angularjs-add-module JHipster will add new module here
        'angular-loading-bar'
    ])
    .run(run);

run.$inject = ['$rootScope', 'stateHandler', 'translationHandler'];

function run($rootScope, stateHandler, translationHandler) {
    $rootScope.isEmbedded = function() {
        if(navigator.userAgent.indexOf('EMBEDDED')!=-1) {
            return true;
        };
        return false;
    };

    stateHandler.initialize();
    translationHandler.initialize();
}
})();
```

Answer (score -1):

If you're using ngRoute then you should have $routeProvider, if using ui-router then it's $stateProvider - which one are you using? Since the error you posted seems to deal directly with $stateProvider I believe it's nothing to do with pattern restrict.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, and bear with my inexperience. I'm using ui-router.